# Selenium - loop through elements check if collection has a value

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having DOM elements with specific values as a text. **In case below it's "Uno"**.

```
<span class="custom-field-value" xpath="1">Uno</span>
```

Elements have the same class but differ only in mentioned text value.

*I would like to check if specific Webelement's text is visible in at least one of the span elements*

**Steps already done:**

- Define IWebElements
- Created list of the elements text value which I will use for comparison:

  ```
    IList<string> customFields = new List<string> { customField1, customField2, customField3, customField4 };
  ```
- I'm having problem with comparison method. I need to pass the list to the method, get from each list Webelement .Text value and then loop through all the elements and check if each text equals to and the one list position. I'm assuming the best way would beto mix for loop with linqu.

  ```
    public bool ValidateCustomFields(IList<string> customFields)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CartCustomFields.Count; i++)
        {
            CartCustomFields.ElementAt(i).Text.
            CartCustomFields.Any(element => element.FindElement(By.XPath(".")).Text)
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: Is your  created customFields data in same order w.r.t webpage?

Comment: I think this should work for you `CartCustomFields.Any(element => element.FindElement(By.XPath(".")).Text==customFields[i])`

Answer (score 0):

if you're checking whether specific text is displayed on UI and it can be in several elements, why not then search for all elements using xpath

```
//span[@class = 'custom-field-value' and text() = 'YOUR_TEXT']
```

and then checking whether the list is empty or not?

Comment: but how to pass each list element inside the IWebElements and then compare it?

Comment: if your goal is just to find webElements with that text, then you don't have to do the compare...or am I missing something?